# Difference script behaviour with bash and tcsh

Tags: bash, shell, tcsh

I'm quite new to shell scripting on Linux (currently using Ubuntu).
I wrote the simple following script (name yourName.sh):

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh -f
echo "What is your first name?"
set firstName = $<
echo "What is your last name?"
set lastName = $<
echo "Hello $firstName $lastName"
```

Now, when I run the script with

```
bash yourName.sh
```

I get the following error:

```
What is your first name?
yourName.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'
yourName.sh: line 3: 'set firstName = $<'
```

When I run the same script with  `tcsh yourName.sh` everything works fine.
Detailed answers appreciated, obviously, but if someone can even just refer me to an article that explains the differences between 'bash' and 'tcsh' it will be a huge help.

Comment: They are two different shells with different syntax. I'm not sure what you were expecting.

Comment: You might want to consider spending your learning energy on something other than tcsh scripting. Such skills would be considered esoteric at best, and if you're called upon to write shell scripts, bourne or bash will be the best option in almost all environments. Also consider that it has been proposed that [csh is actually considered harmful](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html). While tcsh is not precisely csh, it shares many of the structural limitations.

Answer (score 0):

this is bash version of your script; To get input from the keyboard, you use the read command.

```
echo "What is your first name?"
read -r firstName
echo "What is your last name?"
read -r lastName
echo "Hello $firstName $lastName"
```

> read -r   raw input - disables interpretion of backslash escapes and line-continuation in the read data